# Generating android apk file from java commands

Tags: java, android, apk

Can i generate android apk file while running some commands in a java class?

I found some thing like this
http://geosoft.no/development/android.html
and this
http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/233-how-to-build-apk-file-from-command-line

but i just want to create it from file.java class .

Comment: Android APKs need a manifest, you can't simply turn some Java source into an APK

Comment: Could you please give me a start point to begin with..And thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just turn Java source code into an APK, Android projects have certain criteria that has to be met.

You can read about this at the [Android Project Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).

Comment: thank you.i don't want to turn the java code..i want to run a command to generate the apk from existing android folders.